# why exception throws as Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, below is my api controller:

```
// API controller named Movie

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    ....       
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get([FromQuery]int id)
{
  ....         
}
```

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get([FromQuery]string title, [FromQuery]string category)
{
  ....         
}
```

then when I start the appication and routed to `localhost/api/movie/123`, it threw an exception which is **Multiple actions were found that match the request**

but only the first action method match, since there is only one parameter?

Comment: You have a route conflict because both actions map to the same route and the route table does not know which to choose. Also that shown URI does not match neither of the shown actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a route conflict because all those actions map to the same route and the route table does not know which to choose.

Routes need to be unique per action to avoid route conflicts.

In order for `localhost/api/movie/123` to match `Get(int id)` action the route template would need to look like

```
//GET api/movie/123
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public JsonResult Get(int id) {
    //....         
}
```

Note the removal of the `[FromQuery]` and also the use of a route constraint `{id:int}` on the `id` route parameter

The second action should now not conflict with the first

```
//GET api/movie?title=someTitle&category=someCategory
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get([FromQuery]string title, [FromQuery]string category) {
    //....         
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have edit my post to add a new Get action method, this time it still throw an exception

Comment: could you also have a look at this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665394/how-can-i-setup-multiple-action-methods-to-handle-get-request-that-is-only-diffe/59665914#59665914

Comment: @amjad Are you using separate accounts to ask questions?