# how can I setup multiple action methods to handle get request that is only differential by the passing parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, below is my api controller:

```
// API controller named Student

//match localhost/api/student
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    ....       
}

//match localhost/api/student/123
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public JsonResult Get(int id) {
    //....         
}

//match localhost/api/student?sortby=grade
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get([FromQuery]string sortby)
{
  ....         
}

//match localhost/api/student?name=somename&gender=male
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get([FromQuery]string name, [FromQuery]string gender)
{
  ....         
}
```

then when I start the appication and routed to `localhost/api/student`, it threw an exception which is **Multiple actions were found that match the request**

so how can I setup mutiple get request that is differential by the passing parameters?

Comment: can you provide your controllers code

Answer (score 0):

try like this it will work

```
[HttpGet("Get")]
public JsonResult Get()
{
  ....       
}


[HttpGet("Get/{id}")]
public JsonResult Get(int id) 
{
   //....         
}


 [HttpGet("GetFromQuery")]
public JsonResult Get([FromQuery]string sortby)
{
   ....         
}
```